# Tic-Tac-Toe Loop & If issues

Tags: c++

I need to make a two player tic tac toe game that uses a 1-9 grid. The player enters in the number they want there letter to represent. However I can't get it to recognize who wins. After every number entered it says that the last player that entered in a number won.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

int Xp, Op, turn;
char board[9] = {'1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'};

cout << "Please enter a number on the board that is the spot you wish to use" << endl;

cout << "Board:\n";

cout << board[0] << " " << board[1] << " " << board[2] << endl;
cout << board[3] << " " << board[4] << " " << board[5] << endl;
cout << board[6] << " " << board[7] << " " << board[8] << endl;

do
{
for (turn=1; turn<10; turn++)
    if (!(turn % 2) == 0)
    {
        cout << "\nPlayer X's turn." << endl;
        cin >> Xp;
        board[Xp-1] = 'X';

cout << "Current Board:\n";

cout << board[0] << " " << board[1] << " " << board[2] << endl;
cout << board[3] << " " << board[4] << " " << board[5] << endl;
cout << board[6] << " " << board[7] << " " << board[8] << endl;




if((board[0]&&board[1]&&board[2] == 'X') || (board[3]&&board[4]&&board[5] == 'X') || (board[6]&&board[7]&&board[8] == 'X') || 
 (board[0]&&board[3]&&board[6] == 'X') || (board[1]&&board[4]&&board[7] == 'X') || (board[2]&&board[5]&&board[8] == 'X') || 
 (board[0]&&board[4]&&board[8] == 'X') || (board[6]&&board[4]&&board[2] == 'X'));
 {          
   cout << "Player X wins!!!!" << endl;
 }      
    else
    {

        cout << "\nPlayer O's turn." << endl;

        cin >> Op;
        board[Op-1] = 'O';

cout << "Current Board:\n";

cout << board[0] << " " << board[1] << " " << board[2] << endl;
cout << board[3] << " " << board[4] << " " << board[5] << endl;
cout << board[6] << " " << board[7] << " " << board[8] << endl;

if((board[0]&&board[1]&&board[2] == 'O') || (board[3]&&board[4]&&board[5] == 'O') || (board[6]&&board[7]&&board[8] == 'O') || 
 (board[0]&&board[3]&&board[6] == 'O') || (board[1]&&board[4]&&board[7] == 'O') || (board[2]&&board[5]&&board[8] == 'O') || 
 (board[0]&&board[4]&&board[8] == 'O') || (board[6]&&board[4]&&board[2] == 'O'));
{           
cout << "Player O wins!!!!" << endl;
}

    }
}
while(turn<10);

cout << "We have a tie!!!";

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with the if statements that look like this:

```
if((board[0]&&board[1]&&board[2] == 'X') || (board[3]&&board[4]&&board[5] == 'X') || (board[6]&&board[7]&&board[8] == 'X') || 
 (board[0]&&board[3]&&board[6] == 'X') || (board[1]&&board[4]&&board[7] == 'X') || (board[2]&&board[5]&&board[8] == 'X') || 
 (board[0]&&board[4]&&board[8] == 'X') || (board[6]&&board[4]&&board[2] == 'X'));
 {          
   cout << "Player X wins!!!!" << endl;
 }
```

You have a `;` before the block of code that you intend to be the body of the if statement.
The `;` ends the statement making the following block no longer part of the if, but simply a block of code to be executed regardless of the outcome of the condition.

Comment: The syntax should be: `if ((board[0] == 'X') && (board[1] == 'X') && (board[2] == 'X'))`.   Otherwise it is something like this: `if (((board[0] == 1) && (board[1] == 1) && (board[2] == 1)) == 'X'))`.

Comment: @Thomas Matthews Good catch.